# Mismatched List Types

Tags: c#, list, generics, overriding

I have a base class that has an abstract method which returns a list of itself.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public abstract class baseclass
    {
        public abstract List<baseclass> somemethod();        
    }
}
```

And a descendant that tries to override the base class's method by returning a list of **it**self.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class childclass : baseclass
    {
        public override List<childclass> somemethod()
        {
            List<childclass> result = new List<childclass>();
            result.Add(new childclass("test"));
            return result;
        }

        public childclass(string desc)
        {
            Description = desc;
        }

        public string Description;
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error   1   'ConsoleApplication1.childclass.somemethod()':
return type must be 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApplication1.baseclass>'
to match overridden member 'ConsoleApplication1.baseclass.somemethod()' 
C:\Users\josephst\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1childclass.cs 
0   42  ConsoleApplication1
```

What's the best approach to have a base class return a list of itself, overriding the base class's method that does the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic i s nice solution, but don't use `public abstract List<baseclass> somemethod();` it's bad practice

You should use [non-virtual interface pattern](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Canonical_Forms%E2%80%94NVI_Pattern)

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    protected abstract List<T> DoSomeMethod();

    public List<T> SomeMethod()
    {
        return DoSomeMethod();
    }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass<ChildClass>
{
    protected override List<ChildClass> DoSomeMethod(){ ... }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer with this same suggestion, [this may not always do what you want it to do, or think it does.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx)

Comment: You make it seem like this solution is vastly superior, when really it isn't.  It's actually quite flawed.  Can it be used without causing those problems, sure, but then that's true of virtually every design/pattern.

Comment: agree, it's the balance of price and solutions

Answer (score 2):

When overriding a method, a signature of overriding method must *exactly* match the signature of the method being overriden. You can achieve what you want with generics:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    public abstract List<T> SomeMethod();
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass<ChildClass>
{
    public override List<ChildClass> SomeMethod() { ... }
}
```

Comment: [Note that this may not always do what you want it to do, or think it does.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx)

Comment: Won't `public abstract List<T> SomeMethod() where T : BaseClass;`  help?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-explanatory. To override the method you need to return a `List<baseclass>`.

```
public override List<baseclass> somemethod()
{
    List<childclass> result = new List<childclass>();
    result.Add(new childclass("test"));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That resolves the issue, but I want the returned list to have values that are specific to my child class.

Comment: @JosephStyons: You can return a `List<childclass>` as shown above. But the method signature must return a `List<baseclass>` if you want to override the method. You could cast the `baseclass` to `childclass`.